# qemu warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu

I'm tying to install Ubuntu 22.04(guest) on Ubuntu 20.04(host) with Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4.

I installed `qemu`, `qemu-kvm`, `bridge-utils` and added my user to `kvm` group.  But the run command,

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom ~/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso -m 2048 -accel kvm
```

gives an error

```
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The warning might be the result of QEMU presenting a "generic" virtual CPU to the VM by default, and the OS within the VM then testing all the possible CPU features to figure out what the virtual CPU can or cannot do.

`svm` is an AMD processor feature; the equivalent feature on Intel processors is known as `vmx`.

Try adding a `-cpu host` option to your `qemu-system-x86_64` command to use the same CPU type as your actual host CPU, or run `qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu help` to view the list of types of virtual x86_64 CPUs supported by `qemu`, choose an Intel CPU model suitable to your requirements, and use the `-cpu` option to specify it.

For example, since your Intel Core i3-1115G4 is of the Tiger Lake generation, if QEMU does not yet offer that CPU family for VMs, you might try the previous generation of Intel CPUs: `-cpu Icelake-Client`.

Comment: What does `-cpu host` do?

Comment: It's an easy way to say "have the VM's virtual CPUs use the same CPU type as the actual host CPU is".

Comment: Do you know why, despite being on a MacBook and running macOS, trying to host a macOS guest requires `-cpu host,-pdpe1gb` and not just `-cpu host`? I found this surprising. Is `-cpu host` expected to have better performance than emulating CPU?

Comment: @theonlygusti I don't know enough about internals of macOS to be sure. Maybe there is something in macOS that makes it hard for QEMU to provide 1GB memory pages (= the `pdpe1gb` feature flag) for the VM? Or maybe the real Mac firmware always disables this feature and so macOS in the VM gets confused if it finds the feature enabled?